# How to fix following error on windows 10 get modulenotfounderror no module named slugify?

Tags: python, windows

I have installed pip3 python-slugify and pip3 list does show python-slugify 5.0.2; path on installation is added to Environment variable PATH but despite of it
when try to execute:

```
from slugify import slugify
```

I always get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named slugify.
```

My `python --version` shows `3.8.8(def, apr 13.2021) Anaconda build`

python-slugify install is C:\user.....\python39.....

I tried restarting system and reinstalling with pip3 but no luck at all.

How can I fix this issue

Comment: It looks like you have 2 Python installations: 3.8, Anaconda and 3.9, regular Python installation. Installing a module in one does not make it available in the other.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the installation folder with

`pip3 show python-slugify`

thats the site packages folder. In that folder there should be a file slugify.py

Then check the path in python:

```
import sys
for x in sys.path:
    print(x)
```

The folder you get in 1. should be printed.
If not, make sure you are using the pip3 and python from the same python environment.

To see where are the executable use

```
where pip3
```

and

```
where python
```

in the windows console